# Heat dissipation in stepper motor running for long time

Tags: power, motor, heat

**Background**

I want to run a 28BYJ-48 motor for 8 hours a day over a week. I am concerned about the motor overheating throughout the day.

**What I know**

The motor draws 92mA of current and takes 5V, generating approx. 0.5 W of power. I know that power is converted to motion and heat (and that motion is proportional to current, and heat is proportional to current squared).

**Question**

In what proportion is that 0.5 W of power transformed into motion and heat? If this is dependent on some spec of the motor, what spec should I be looking at?

Comment: It would be simplest, and perhaps not that inaccurate depending on what it is doing, to assume that it is *all* turned into heat.  The actual fractions could only be calculated by determining the mechanical work performed on an external load.

Comment: Does the datasheet for the motor (no link provided in your question) give a rating? What safety factor have you got at 0.5 W?

Answer (score 1):

If you're operating the motor within spec, you should assume that it will be happy. There are exceptions, since some devices are only rated for intermittent use. Examples are solenoids, which are often not rated for continuous use, and cheap laser modules from China on eBay. Motors, though, are generally good. Especially, try to mount the motor to a metal plate if you're worried. Alternatively, just take a motor, power it up, and leave it running for a day on a nice fireproof surface and see what happens. If you can touch it without raising a blister you should be fine. Come on, where's your sense of adventure?